# Persisting HTML documents to disk

Tags: html, r, persistence

I am trying to save about 300 HTML objects to disk using R.

```
str_url <- "https://www.holidayhouses.co.nz/Browse/List.aspx?page=1"
read_html_test1 <- xml2::read_html(str_url)

xml2::write_xml(read_html_test1, "testwrite.html")
read_html <- xml2::read_html("testwrite.html")
```

But this will eventually save about 300 separate files to disk.  Ideally, what I would like is to save a single R object to disk that contains these 300 documents.

Converting each document to text before saving for some reason does not work.  For example the following will product some weird (unhelpful) error:

```
str_html <- as.character(read_html_test1)
xml2::read_html(str_html)
```

If I try to use the output of `xml2::read_html()` it is a a pointer to a C structure and therefore this will not persist to disk.

Any suggestions for a hack to make this work...?

Comment: Put them in a list and use `saveRDS`?

Comment: Does not work @alistaire. The object created by saveRDS does not contain data...just some pointers to c objects. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it with the `httr` package, whose `content` function can take an `as = "text"` argument, which stops it from parsing the HTML.

```
library(xml2)
library(httr)

str_url <- "https://www.holidayhouses.co.nz/Browse/List.aspx?page=1"

# use `GET` to make the request, and pull out the html with `content`; returns text string
x <- content(GET(str_url), as = 'text')

# make a list of html documents to save
list_xs <- list(x, x)

# save list with `saveRDS`
saveRDS(list_xs, 'test.rds')
```

Now to see if it works:

```
# read in rds file we saved
saved_html <- readRDS('test.rds')

# parse the second element in it with `xml2::read_html`
saved_x_parsed <- read_html(saved_html[[2]])

# and let's see...
saved_x_parsed

# {xml_document}
# <html>
# [1] <head><title>&#13;\n\tNew Zealand holiday homes, baches and vacation homes for rent.&#13;\ ...
# [2] <body id="ctl00_Body" class="Page-List">&#13;\n    <div class="SatNavBarPlaceholder"/>&#13 ...
```

Comment: Its a beauty @alistaire.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How to save R objects to disk:

[Save R Objects](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)

I took your example code and produced working, human readable, R-loadable output as follows:

```
str_url <- "https://www.holidayhouses.co.nz/Browse/List.aspx?page=1"
read_html_test1 <- xml2::read_html(str_url)
str_html <- as.character(read_html_test1)
x <- xml2::read_html(str_html)
save(x, file="c:\\temp\\text.txt",compress=FALSE,ascii=TRUE)
```

Comment: You need to quote the relevant parts of a link in your answer in case the destination changes.

Comment: Thanks @JLB  the code that you posted broke for me on the line (xml2::read_html(str_html))  mmmm I am not sure where it does this...?